# FileOutputStream : FileNotFoundException when attempting to instantiate

Tags: java, android, io, fileoutputstream

Trying to create and write to a file, but i get a `FileNotFoundException` every time, here is the method i am using:

```
public void saveFileAsPRN(Context context){
    byte[] dataFile = getPrintableFileData();


    String filename = "TestPrn.prn"; 

    // instantiate a file object using the path
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename);
    Log.e(TAG, Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());

    //determine if the media is mounted with read & write access
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "media mounted"); //good
    }else{
        Log.e(TAG, "media NOT mounted"); //bad
    }

    //create directory if it does not exist
    //the default Download directory should always exist
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Directory not created");
    }

    // determine if the file exists, create it if it does not
    if(!file.exists()){
        try {
            Log.e(TAG, "File does not exist, creating..");
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        Log.e(TAG, "File Exists");
    }    

    //this makes the blank file visible in the file browser
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/" + filename}, null, null);

    //create output stream - send data; saving to file
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {           
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file); // <---- CRASHES HERE; FileNotFoundException              
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        out.write(dataFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

A `FileNotFoundException` is raised on the following line:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(file); // <---- CRASHES HERE;
```

The directory Exists, and a blank file is created in the target directory (visible by browsing target folder on PC).

Calling the method `canWrite()` on the `File` object returns true - i have write access.

The manifest contains: `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`"

So i'm out of ideas, i see several people have similar issues, but i cant find an answer.

Comment: What does http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile() return? Also, won't `mkdirs()` create your file as a directory?

Comment: check for reader if you are able to read it and also try PrintWriter for writing data to the file, it can directly take the File object.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the following code fixed the issue:

```
//create directory if it does not exist
//the default Download directory should always exist
if (!file.mkdirs()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Directory not created");
}
```

that code does create a blank file, you can see it contained in the folder,
BUT - it's very misleading; you can't do anything with this file, i tried transferring it from my device to my PC and i couldn't, i also cannot open it. and you cannot open a stream to it in code.

Comment: That's because `new File("hello/world").mkdirs()` will result in two directories. See https://gist.github.com/sldblog/7007108

Answer (score 0):

Try this may helps you.

Replace this line

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename);
```

With

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath(), filename);
```